# Tcl - replacement/match/uniquify

Tags: string, tcl, substitution

Input:

```
set game1 base_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game2 base_ball_20_200_d_e_f
set game3 base_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game4 base_bat_50_500_m_n_o
set game5 tennis_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game6 tennis_ball_20 200_d_e_f
set game7 tennis_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game8 tennis_bat_50_500_m_n_o
```

Output needs to be uniquified and print out as below.

```
set game1 bb1_digit1
set game2 bb1_digit2
set game3 bb1_digit3
set game4 bb2_digit4
set game1 bb3_digit1
set game2 bb3_digit2
set game4 bb4_digit3
set game5 bb4_digit4
```

How can I replace `base_ball` -> `bb*`?

How can I replace `10_100_a_b_c` -> `digit*`?

What are the tcl command to perform this task?

Comment: Please review `Input` and `Output`, they don't seem to correlate well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick-and-dirty go at this:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set input {
set game1 base_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game2 base_ball_20_200_d_e_f
set game3 base_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game4 base_bat_50_500_m_n_o
set game5 tennis_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game6 tennis_ball_20_200_d_e_f
set game7 tennis_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game8 tennis_bat_50_500_m_n_o
}

set bbs [list]
set digits [list]
foreach { k1 k2 k3 } $input {
    if { ![regexp {^([^0-9]+)(.*)$} $k3 - bb digit] } {
        error "invalid input $k3"
    }

    set bb_index [lsearch -exact $bbs $bb]
    if { $bb_index < 0 } {
        lappend bbs $bb
        set bb_index [lsearch -exact $bbs $bb]
    }

    set digit_index [lsearch -exact $digits $digit]
    if { $digit_index < 0 } {
        lappend digits $digit
        set digit_index [lsearch -exact $digits $digit]
    }

    puts "$k1 $k2 bb[expr {${bb_index}+1}]_digit[expr {${digit_index}+1}]"
}
```

... and the terminal output:

```
set game1 bb1_digit1
set game2 bb1_digit2
set game3 bb2_digit3
set game4 bb2_digit4
set game5 bb3_digit1
set game6 bb3_digit2
set game7 bb4_digit3
set game8 bb4_digit4
```

The output is a little different from what's in your question, but I assume this is what you had in mind.

---

If input is to come from a file, you can replace

```
set input {
set game1 base_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game2 base_ball_20_200_d_e_f
set game3 base_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game4 base_bat_50_500_m_n_o
set game5 tennis_ball_10_100_a_b_c
set game6 tennis_ball_20_200_d_e_f
set game7 tennis_bat_40_400_j_k_l
set game8 tennis_bat_50_500_m_n_o
}
```

with

```
set fd [open "name_of_file"]
set input [read $fd]
close $fd
```

Comment: How do you pass the inputs as a file? The inputs list is all in a file.

Comment: You can replace `set input { .... }` with `set input [read stdin]`.  Then run the script and provide the input file via stdin redirection: `... < input_file`.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: Could you pls explain how does the bb_index knows how to match  (base_ball, base_bat, tennis_ball, tennis_bat) and digit_index knows how to match (50_500_m_n_o, 20_200_d_e_f, etc) since both bb_index and digit_index are in K3? I guess my question is how does the set bb_index (lsearch) and set digit_index (lsearch) works?

Comment: In the example, the regular expression `([^0-9]+)` matches everything up to, but not including, the first digit.  The subsequent regular expressions `(.*)` matches everything else that follows (i.e. from first digit to end of string).  These get assigned to `bb` and `digit`, respectively.

Comment: What should I do, if I inputs format as follow: set game1 base_ball_ABCD_100_100_CDEF_GHIK (for all the set game*)? Currently, I am not able to get the output you got with your code, I am suspectiing, my input set game1 ilist s not exactly as your  input list?

Comment: It seems like I need a regexp that will match base_ball and then match ABCD_100_100_CDEF_GHIK

Comment: @jay how many different prefixes are possible?  `base_ball_`, `base_bat_`, `tennis_ball_`, `tennis_bat_`... ?  You example is not clear about where the split should happen.  If you can articulate the rule that splits the string into two parts, I can help you come up with the correct regular expression.